# Partition size differ in fdisk and df by 240 GB. why?

Tags: linux, partition, disk-usage

I have a **4 TB** Seagate Drive. Apart from **22 GiB** of other partitions, there rest is for `sda1`.

The Problem? I miss about **240 GiB** of `sda1`! I can't see where it is.

whole `sda1` partition has a filesystem in it:

```
root@nas2:/disk1# resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.46.6 (1-Feb-2023)
The filesystem is already 970893568 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

And here is the output of `tune2fs`:

```
root@nas2:/disk1# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.46.6 (1-Feb-2023)
Filesystem volume name:   media
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Inode count:              242728960
Block count:              970893568
Reserved block count:     48544677
Overhead clusters:        15514514
Free blocks:              90623795
Free inodes:              242586218
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
```

`fdisk -l` shows total size of `sda1` as **3703 GiB**.

```
root@nas2:/disk1# fdisk -l /dev/sda1
Disk /dev/sda1: 3.62 TiB, 3976780054528 bytes, 7767148544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

but `df -h -BK` shows **3459959268K used + 167361856K available** for `sda1`. which equals to **3459 GiB**:

```
root@nas2:/disk1# df -h -BK
Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      3821516216K 3459959268K 167361856K  96% /srv/dev-disk...
```

That's a difference of **244 GiB** on a **3726 GiB** Hard drive. 6 percent of the disk is missing!
where do you think is it?

Comment: without having much time I'd point you to `Reserved block count: 48544677`

Comment: in other words, I always specify `-m 0` which is reserved for `root` space

Comment: i.e. `48544677/970893568 = 0.0499999` ... default reserved blocks is 5% ... also: 48544677 is about 185GiB - so, there's another 59GiB to account for ... which is around 15500000 4k blocks ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out reserved block count. This hard drive is used for data storage and no OS will ever be installed on it (there were before, but on 20GB HDD partition, not on this one. is there a way to remove this reserved for root blocks?

Comment: Ok. I removed it by running `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1`. But still 60 GB is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 970893568 blocks of 4096 bytes on the partition, which are the 3976780054528 bytes ; 3703,67 GiB

You need space for the inode table, read about inodes where the meta data (i.e access rights) of a file is stored.
you have an inode count of -> Inode count:              242728960 
242728960 possible inodes for the partition.
each inode uses 256 byte, so you have 242728960*256/4096= 15170560 blocks needed for inodes.
inode table: ~ 57,87 GiB 
than you have reserved blocks for root:
Reserved block count:     48544677 * 4096 /1024^3 = 185GiB

Do you have a journal? how many blocks for the journal size?
`sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1`

sorry cant comment.